# Azure appfabric cache, serialization issues with anonymous classes from Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, caching, serialization, azure

I'm having trouble putting a List<> of an anonymous class into the cache.

```
var cache = new DataCacheFactory().GetCache("default");
var parts = somethingIQueryable.Select(i => new { i.s1, i.s2 } );
cache.Put("somekey", parts.ToList(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

This throws a serialization exception. However it works if I put the data in a class like this:

```
public class A { public string s1, public string s2 }    

var cache = new DataCacheFactory().GetCache("default");
var parts = somethingIQueryable.Select(i => new A { s1 = i.s1, s2 = i.s2 } );
cache.Put("somekey", parts.ToList(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

I would rather not have to define classes for every little bit of data going into the cache though, and was wondering if there is a way to make the first example work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to serialize anonymous types and store them in a cache like this and unfortunately, would need to create `List<A>` and store this.

This would be because there is nothing to compare the anonymous type against to do the serialization and deserialization. Simply, it has no way of knowing what the anonymous type is, because as it's name implies, it is anonymous.

Comment: Booo. The ASP.Net cache can deal with it just fine, but I guess that means it stores the objects themselves in memory without serializing or something.

Comment: I believe this would be the case, yes.

Comment: ..and of course that whilst there are benefits to storing in memory (not needing to serialize is one) there are also quite disadvantages - cache is not shared accross processes, is less durable, memory pressure on web server, etc. so one simply has to weight the options and make the call...